# Minikube connectex issue on Windows 10 Enterprise with Hyper-V

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

My laptop configuration: Windows 10 Enterprise with Hyper-V (rather than Virtual box).

I was following some Kubernetes tutorial and while doing so my internet connection went down for some time. Later, I resumed the learning but I got the following error and was not able to proceed:

```
C:\kubernetes\demo>minikube version
minikube version: v1.10.1
commit: 63ab801ac27e5742ae442ce36dff7877dcccb278

C:\kubernetes\demo>kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.18.0
Server Version: v1.18.2

C:\kubernetes\demo>minikube ip
192.168.1.103
C:\kubernetes\demo>kubectl get all
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.1.103:8443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Also, from the command: 'minikube logs', I see:

```
* E0529 17:56:11.077679       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/r2d4/external-storage/lib/controller/controller.go:412: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/persistentvolumes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: getsockopt: no route to host
* E0529 17:56:11.077719       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/r2d4/external-storage/lib/controller/controller.go:411: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: getsockopt: no route to host
```

I did search on the google for this issue but eventually in vain.

Any pointers ?

Edit 1: This happens (as per my observation), when ever there is a change in network/internet (when I off/on VPN, example). Removal and ReInstall of minikube is not a feasible option all the time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did run the below command and it is working fine until now.

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv
```

previously, I was running the below command and ran into issue multiple times as discussed in question.

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch"
```

Here, I did create the "Primary Virtual Switch and probably this could be the potential virtual switch that was causing this issue.